# Setting up PHPUnit with Gitlab Continuous Integration

Tags: git, unit-testing, continuous-integration, phpunit, gitlab

I've been tasked with investigating Continuous Integration, and one of the things I am looking at is Gitlab CI.

I have set up Gitlab, Gitlab CI and two runners, but I am absolutely stuck on how to really use this. How could I do something like create a unit test, push that to the repo, and have one of the runners test it?

Or am I completely missing the point here? I'm new to this CI stuff (as in, I was asked to do this yesterday and that's the first time I've come in contact with CI) so if I'm missing the point, please let me know and point me towards some resources.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that in the settings for either the runners or the repo in the CI panel, there is a scripts window. This can be used to directly execute shell commands, such as `phpunit -c /path/to/tests`, and will work out whether the tests have failed or passed.

I think this might be due to PHPUnit outputting to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, but I don't really know - not part of the scope so I haven't looked into it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You ask a pretty wide question here. You were tasked to learn about CI. You got GitLab CI and you don't know how to use it. I'm going to first respond to ask if you understand the difference between a build and a script execution? PHP is executed as a pre-process within a web server prior to sending HTTP content. It's not a build. Java or C++ would be compiled and built. I was going to recommend that you look at the open source SCons but then realized that it's for compiled builds.

My second question is are you using a source control repository? If so, which one? For PHP I might use Ruby and write my own continuous integration tools. I'm not quite sure. Answer my questions. I would like to continue this discussion and help you solve this with excellence.